# AWS Instance Security Group to give access to itself via TCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I have an Apache server running the front end (Angular) which relies on an API which is hosted on the same instance as the Apache. I don't want my API (Express) open to public yet but need access to it with my front end which shares the same IP. Things I've tried,

- Setting API base url as 'localhost' doesn't seem to work.
- Adding a security rule in AWS security groups to allow connections only to the same IP (to itself) doesn't work.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What server provides that API? If that is an Apache, it might be possible to write proper rules to serve some directory only for `localhost`

Comment: Apache is used to serve an Angular front-end App. NodeJS, Express is used for the API. Do you mean CORS to serve only to localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Connections to same IP are always open by default. You may need to add `private IP` of the ec2 instance as your api base URL. (Port you know better). Cors too should be enabled for that private IP.

Comment: it looks like CORS is the only option because setting a private IP in the front end would result in the app searching the IP in the client computer. I'm going to try to see if I can only allow connections from frontend to the API using CORS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using Angular as the front-end means needing an API that can access publicly you just need to implement securities, because you just serve the UI to the client user and their browsers are the one accessing the API not the server of the angular.
You can setup another API which can be deploy on the same server of your UI and same url which will serve as controller of your "Private API" that you can manage using Security groups in AWS

Comment: Yes I've started to realize this and I've decided to see if I can block origin address from the Node server CORS. Do you have any other suggestions I could try?

Comment: You can add that origin blocking but it can always alter that request. Just implement a good tokenisation with secret key on both APIs

Answer (score 0):

Replaced ${IP} to 172.17.0.1 so it can connect to the same EC2 after restarting. Add a rule for the inbound connection from the same SG